# Radio button checked property

Tags: php, radio-button

How can I know if the radio button checked property is true in PHP, can anyone give me an example?

Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to ask for the checked attribute, see the example:

```
<label for="public0"><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="publicar" id="public0" value="TRUE" /> YES</label>
<label for="public1"><input type="radio" name="publicar" id="public1" value="FALSE" /> NO</label>
```

Then get the value of the raddio button in php: **$publicar=$postvars['publicar'];** and ask for its value in order to know if it is TRUE or FALSE

In addition, if you want to manipulate the values using javascript:

```
if ( $("public0").checked == true) 
{ ...} or if ( $("public1").checked == true){...}
 //alert($("public0").checked); //if you want to see the value
  //alert($("public1").checked);
```

Note: $postvars=$_POST

Answer (score 12):

After submitting your form, in $_POST (or $_GET respectively) you'll have a key with your radio button name and value with your radio button value, if it was checked. Otherwise, there will be no such key at all.

So `<input type="radio" name="test" value="checked!" checked="checked" />`
Will produce `$_POST['test'] == 'checked!'`

Answer (score 2):

If your checkbox is checked, it is represented by a `key=>value` pair in your $_POST or $_GET array. So, if you want a boolean to know if it's checked or not use this:

```
$checked = (isset($_POST['checkbox_name']))?true:false;
```

If you want the actual value of the checkbox:

```
$checked = (isset($_POST['checkbox_name']))?$_POST['checkbox_name']:NULL;
```

Replace $_POST with $_GET, depending on the method of your form.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your radio button `name`
For example, if you got 2 radio buttons with `name = 'gender'` and you checked the one with `value='male'`, you'll have in PHP `$_POST['gender']` equals to `male` (or $_GET with GET)