# How to check if radio is checked?

Tags: php, radio-button

How to check if radio button is checked after post?

Code on my radio button

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Ingredient') echo 'checked="checked" ';?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Miscellaneous') echo 'checked="checked" ';?>
```

code to check my radio:

```
$Itemtype = $_POST["Itemtype"];

if($_POST["Itemtype"] == "Ingredient")
{
    $try2 = "ingred. working";
]
elseif($_POST["Itemtype"] == "Miscellaneous")
{
    $try2 = "misc. working";
}
else
{
    $errormsg = "error5";
}
```

If I don't select a radio button it says "syntax error: undefined Index Itemtype" keeps aiming at the  `$Itemtype = $_POST["Itemtype"];`

and if i select radio button it doesn't return checked on the selected radio button.

anyone can give me helping hand on this thanks.

Comment: Use `isset` ... `$checked = isset($_POST['checkbox'])) ? true : false;`

Comment: Exactly in the same way as you've done it before: `if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']) && $_POST['Itemtype'] == 'Miscellaneous')`...

Comment: FDL is correct, the browser won't even send a POST parameter for a group of radios unless one is checked. The second issue might be easier to help with if you include your HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio button checked property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976534/radio-button-checked-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?  
    $_POST['Itemtype'] = "Ingredient";
    if(isset($_POST['Itemtype'])) {
        $Itemtype = $_POST["Itemtype"]; 
        if($_POST["Itemtype"] == "Ingredient") {
            $try2 = "ingred. working"; 
        }elseif($_POST["Itemtype"] == "Miscellaneous"){
            $try2 = "misc. working"; 
        } 
    } else { $errormsg = 'error5'; }
    echo $try2;
    echo $errormsg;
?>
```

I forced the Itemtype for debugging reasons... This would show your logic works... Question I have is are you echoing out your $try2....

Comment: can i ask whats the use of the `$_POST['Itemtype'] = "Ingredient";` in the very beginning? sorry newbei

Comment: I did that to make the php think it was from a form... You would want to delete it for yourself... But your logic works, so if it doesn't work chances are you have a problem with your form... I would use strtolower or strtoupper when you compare values to eliminate a case sensitive result.

Comment: im just using $try2 to test if it works if itemtype = ingredient. but il be probably eachoing something  under itemtype= ingredient and misc. there will be 2 more nest of if else statement i need to place on it.

Comment: I would look into using a switch. http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: if i use switch can i do something like this?
`switch ($Itemtype) {
    case Ingredient:
        if(isset)
  {
  }
  else
  {
  }
        break;
    case Misc.:
         if(isset)
  {
   if(isset)
   {
   }
   else
   {
   }
  }
  else
  {
  }
        break;
  }` or i messed up? :D i only used switch once before so im not sure if what im doing is right on switch

Comment: You could, but I really don't see the reason you would want to use isset some many times... Write some code and post back here if you run into problems... I find it best to learn through mistakes at times.

Comment: i made a new question for switch incase someone like me might need it also its here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329911/how-to-properly-use-switch-function-in-php this is what ive come up by using switch

Comment: hi again, can i ask for ur help again on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347677/how-to-properly-make-drop-down-list-menu-for-my-tbl-item-in-php?noredirect=1#comment33966008_22347677 these?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use isset if the radio option wasn't ticked it won't be set.

To check it radio button has been checked (and posted) you can like this

```
if (isset($_POST['Itemtype'])) { // if ANY radio button was ticked at all
  echo $_POST['Itemtype']; // display the 'value' the choice that was ticked.
} else {
  echo "no radio button ticked.";
}
```

The 'Itemtype' needs to refer to the name='' field withing your radio button like so.

```
<input type="radio" name="Itemtype" value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="Itemtype" value="male">Male
```

Comment: You have a syntax error with the stray `{`.

Comment: Additionally you could use a switch to echo out something based on the $_POST['Itemtype'] value at the point where Matt echoed it out!

Comment: thanks that helps me but still doesn't return checked value of the radio button. i wonder if browser have something to do with it?

Comment: replace echo $_POST['Itemtype']; with $result = $_POST['Itemtype']; then you can use $result as your returned value.

Comment: heres what im come up on:`if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']))         {         $Itemtype = $_POST["Itemtype"];          if($_POST["Itemtype"] == "Ingredient")          {            $try2 = "ingred. working";          }          elseif($_POST["Itemtype"] == "Miscellaneous")          {           $try2 = "misc. working";          }         }         else         {          $errormsg = 'error5';         }`

Comment: it shouldn't... Do you have your form code? @blackmaler You could use <?php foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ echo $key .": " . $value; } to see what is being passed into the post.

Comment: @Martin E. yea i do have `<form action="" method="post"></form>` cant use php foreach. im not familiar on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The web browser will only pass the value inside `POST` if the radio has been checked by the user.

Update your code as follows to check if the radio has been selected:

```
if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']))
{
    if($_POST["Itemtype"] == "Ingredient")
    { 
        $try2 = "ingred. working";
    }
    elseif($_POST["Itemtype"] == "Miscellaneous")
    {
        $try2 = "misc. working";
    }
}
else
{
    $errormsg = 'error5';
}
```