# how to properly use switch function in php

Tags: php, switch-statement

i want to use switch function on value of radio button but i don't know how to proper use it.

```
 if(isset($_POST['Itemtype']))
    {
    $Itemtype = $_POST["Itemtype"];                             
switch ($Itemtype)
    {
    case "Ingredient":
    $Brandname = $_POST["Brandname"];

if(isset($_POST['Brandname']))
    {
    $try2 = "Brandname working";
    }
    else
    {
    $errormsg = 'error on branchname';
    }
    break;
    case "Miscellaneous":
    $Size = $_POST["Size"];
    $Color = $_POST["Color"];
    if(isset($_POST['Size']))
    {
    $try2 = "Misc working";
    }
    else
    {
    $errormsg = 'error on size';
    break;
    }
  else
{
$errormsg = 'error5';
}
```

my bad on the string part :) but it doesn't check if brandname is set or null.

Comment: `case 'Ingredient'` because its a string

Comment: should i make it 
`case "Ingredient";`?

Comment: `case 'Ingredient':` and `case 'Miscellaneous':` you just need `''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is that your strings aren't inside quotes ex : case Miscellaneous: should be case "Miscellaneous":

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap Ingredient in " so your code should look like the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['Itemtype'])){

  $Itemtype = $_POST["Itemtype"];  
  switch ($Itemtype){

    case "Ingredient":
       $Brandname = $_POST["Brandname"];

       if(isset($_POST['Brandname'])){
        $try2 = "Brandname working";
       }
       else{
        $errormsg = 'error on branchname';
       }
    break;


    case "Miscellaneous":
      $Size = $_POST["Size"];
      $Color = $_POST["Color"];

      if(isset($_POST['Size'])){
        $try2 = "Misc working";
      }
      else{
        $errormsg = 'error on size';
      }
    break;

  }

}
else{
  $errormsg = 'error5';
}
```

Comment: yea my bad...  i was about to edit it when that read only thing came up :)
i figure out everything...