# php radio button value (email form)

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple contact form that works great. I'm trying to add two radio buttons for a user to select. The choice they select will show up in the email I receive. How do I go about obtaining the value they select from the radio buttons?

```
html:

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-">
                        <label class="radio-inline "><input type="radio" name="current" checked>I'm an existing client</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 pb-2">
                        <label class="radio-inline "><input type="radio" name="not-current">I'm not a client yet</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>


PHP:
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$organization = $_POST['organization'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_from = 'Contact Us';
$email_subject = 'New Message';
$email_body = "First Name: $firstname.\n".
              "Last Name: $lastname.\n".
              "Email: $email.\n".
              "Company: $organization.\n".
              "Phone: $phone.\n".
              "Zip Code: $zip.\n".
              "Message: $message.\n";

$to ="email@email.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header("location: thankyou.html");
?>
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3976534/1531971

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio buttons are group together by having same name but different value. So the name would be IsClient and values will be Yes or No

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-">
       <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="client" value="current" checked>I'm an existing client
       </label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6 pb-2">
       <label class="radio-inline ">
           <input type="radio" name="name="client" value="not-current">I'm not a client yet
       </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then in php you will simply read the value of client like this

```
$client = $_POST["client"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same name for input type radio, then set the value. 
You can get the value by simply using $_POST['Your_Radio_Name']